# Prove that the overlap of some two of these surfaces has an area greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{9}$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

**The union of nine planar surfaces, each of area equal to 1, has a total area equal to 5. Prove that the overlap of some two of these surfaces has an area greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{9}$.**

It is 5 task from the "Putnam and Beyond". I invented decision distinct from the book, which is as follows: The number of ways to select pairs of 9 surfaces is expressed through ${9 \choose 2}$ = 36. So suppose that ever intersection has an area of at least $\frac{1}{9}$ and total interception area will be 36 * $\frac{1}{9}$ = 4 and total union area will be 9 - 4 = 5, which proves. My questions:

Is my reasonings are right and if so, is it even possible to place 9 surfaces so that each pairwise intersection is ${9 \choose 2}$, and how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be reading what you wrote wrong, given the translation.

Here is my interpretation of what you mean

1. Let the surfaces be $S_i$.
2. Proof by contradiction. Suppose $|S_i \cap S_k | < \frac{1}{9}$.
3. By Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, $| \cup S_i| =  \sum |S_i| - \sum | S_i \cap S_j | + \ldots $.
4. We claim that RHS $ \geq \sum |S_i| - \sum | S_i \cap S_j |$.
5. Hence $ 5 = | \cup S_i|  \geq \sum |S_i| - \sum | S_i \cap S_j | > 9 - 36 \times \frac{1}{9} = 5$ which is a contradiction.

If so, step 4 isn't covered as yet.

---

Here's another approach.

**Hint:** Prove by contradiction.

$|\cup S_i| = |S_1| + |S_2 - S_1 | + |S_3 - S_2 - S_1 | + \ldots$.

Note that $ 1 + \frac{8}{9} + \frac{7}{9} + \ldots + \frac{1}{9} = \frac { 9 \times 10 } { 9 \times 2 } = 5 $.

Comment: thank u, but what is RHS?

Comment: Right Hand Side.